# Which router do I want to mimic or have the same feature as the Mobile Hotspot on Windows 10?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, hotspot

I'm in the UK using Public [BT WiFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BT_Wi-fi). I have many WiFi enabled devices which do not work with this WiFi because it uses a login page. My workaround is to connect my laptop to the BT WiFi, log in through the network page, and then create a Mobile Hotspot on my PC and connect everything through that. Therefore I can have my own private network where I use setup things like Chromecasts and Sonus Speakerd.

I would like to connect my various WiFi-enabled devices through a router instead of a Mobile Hotspot on my laptop. How must a router be configured to behave like my laptop's Hotspot? Are there any features or wireless standards that must be supported by the router to both connect to a wireless network and simultaneously accept wireless client connections?

One last and possibly really stupid question: *Due to BT Wi-Fi giving similar speeds to each device it connects can I get a router to connect to BT Wi-Fi multiple times and then output that through one Wi-Fi connection for increased speeds?* I sorry if that is a stupid question but I thought I would ask anyone because I would like to know?

Comment: The answer to your last question is "no".   (I don't want to attempt to answer the rest because I am unsure how your cellphone is acting as both a hotspot and AP client at the same time - I wonder if its using the 2.4 gig band for the hotspot and the 5 gig band for the AP client or something like that.

Comment: @davidgo: Either that, or it just performs both tasks _on the same channel._ There's no technical requirement for separate radios.